# How to not default DocuSign initial with signature?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

How do I generate a blank "Initial" when sending someone to DocuSign to sign a document? It is currently generating the initials based upon the name of the signer, but the problem is that the signer might have PHD or something added to the end of their name. Thanks!

Comment: While sending a document for a signature, you can not put an Initial tab value, can you share your code and screenshot of what you are sending and what your users are seeing. Normally at the time of Signing, a user has an option to adopt an Initial/Signature and can edit his/her name as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's an account setting called `SignInEachLocation` that might be what you are after. Normally the DocuSign platform gives you the option to adopt one of the pre-generated signature and initial styles however if you don't want that and instead want your signers to sign and initial in each location you can enable this property on a per recipient basis.

Here is the description from the DocuSign [API Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign):

**signInEachLocation**

`When set to true and the feature is enabled in the sender's account, the signing recipient is required to draw signatures and initials at each signature/initial tab (instead of adopting a signature/initial style or only drawing a signature/initial once).`

This property is configured on the individual `signer` objects in your envelope definitions, for example:

```
{
    "status": "sent",
    "emailSubject": "Request a signature via email example",
    "documents": [{
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "contract.pdf",
        "documentBase64": "base64 encoded bytes..."
    }],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [{
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "john.doe@docusign.com",
            "recipientId": "1",
            --> "signInEachLocation": "true",
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [{
                    "xPosition": "25",
                    "yPosition": "50",
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "pageNumber": "1"
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```